# Hook into add to cart method to execute a custom function before

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

When clicking on the 'Add to cart' button on the single product page, I’d like to execute a custom function right before the original add to cart function is fired.

I added a custom JS click event to the add to cart button but then both function are executed at the same time which is not the behaviour I’d like to have.

```
$( '.button' ).on( 'click', function() {
   // custom function
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to validate cart items?

Could you hook into the:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'your_function', 10, 5 );
```